# choose git submodule depending on the target repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project that I am pushing to 2 different repositories using the following in the `.git/config` file :

```
    [remote "origin"]
        url = the_main_repo
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [remote "other_repo"]
        url = the_other_repo
```

The project itself also has a submodule. My `.gitmodules` file looks like :

```
    [submodule "the_submodule"]
        path = the_submodule
        url = the_submodule_repo_url
```

I would like the `the_submodule_repo_url` to be different depending on which repo I'm pulling from so that I get the submodule repo from the same source (those are different servers in my network).

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Git thinks there should be one URL for a submodule so there is no simple way to do what you want. Git can [substitute URLs on the fly](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) but in your case it should be used dynamically (in the command line, not in a config).

Set one URL for the submodule to the same host as one of the remotes. For the other remote run

```
git -c url.$the_other_submodule_repo.insteadOf the_submodule_repo_url fetch/push/pull other_repo
```

Create a shell script, function or git alias to simplify calling it.